# Grails controllers

Tags: grails, controllers

I have a form similar to this one in Grails:

Name: ***_*____**

Age: ***_*____**

Street: ***_*__*_*_**

Email: ***_*__*_***

|Submit|

How can i pass all the filled in information to a controller that will add me the records to the database? Im kinda new to Grails, and my problem is i dont understand how to "pass" and get things to the controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Person {
   String name
   Integer age
   String street
   String email
}

class PersonController {
    def save = {
        def personInstance = new Person(params)
        personInstance.save(flush:true)
    }
}

<g:form controller="person" action="save">
    <g:textField name="name" />
    <g:textField name="age" />
    <g:textField name="street" />
    <g:textField name="email" />
    <g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" />
</g:form>
```

Also, if you have a domain, you can run

```
grails generate-all com.foo.Person
```

And all the code will be generated for you.  Then you can see how it is done.

Comment: i got it now :p what about if my form have object from multiple domain classes how can i save both in the same submitbutton ?

Comment: @John see "Data binding with Multiple domain classes" at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding

Comment: ok. thank you very much for your help i'll accept the answer. Please if you have sometime, check my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930797/grails-controllers-render-errors.

Comment: ill figure the data binding multiple domain classes by myself